# Custom Painting - Scrollbars not Appearing in JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, scrollbar, jscrollpane

I want to draw Strings and Rectagles on a JPanel.

I'm adding a JPanel to a JScrollPane but if i draw some Strings no scrollbar appears.

Here is some code for example.

```
package gui;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class MainView extends JFrame {

    private SelfDrawnPanel sdp;
    private JScrollPane jsp;

    public MainView(){
        super("TestProgram");
        this.setSize(300, 300);

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        this.sdp = new SelfDrawnPanel();
        this.jsp = new JScrollPane(this.sdp);

        this.add(this.jsp);

        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    class SelfDrawnPanel extends JPanel {

        public void paint(Graphics g) {

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.drawString("test", 10, (i*10)+10);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scrollbars appear when the preferred size of the `ViewportView` component is greater than that of the `JScrollPane`. Currently the `JPanel` `SelfDrawnPanel` has a very small (`10 x 10`) preferred size. Set the preferred size by overriding `getPreferredSize`:

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(400, 1010);
}
```

Aside: Custom painting in Swing is done by overriding `paintComponent` rather than `paint`. Also remember to invoke `super.paintComponent(g)` and use the `@Override` annotation. Read about custom painting [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)